# Failing to set the user agent via httr::user_agent

Tags: r, user-agent, httr

Is there anything special I need to consider when trying to change the user agent via `httr::user_agent` in a `httr::GET()` call on MS Windows? I'm using `R-3.1.0` and `httr 0.3`.

Following the example at `?user_agent`, I'm getting these results:

```
url_this <- "http://httpbin.org/user-agent"
```

Standard user agent:

```
GET(url_this)   
Response [http://httpbin.org/user-agent]
  Status: 200
  Content-type: application/json
{
  "user-agent": "curl/7.19.6 Rcurl/1.95.4.1 httr/0.3"
}
```

Modified user agent:

```
GET(url_this, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"))
Response [http://httpbin.org/user-agent]
  Status: 200
  Content-type: application/json
{
  "user-agent": "curl/7.19.6 Rcurl/1.95.4.1 httr/0.3"
}
```

I had expected that the second call returns something closer to what I'm getting when visiting `url_this` in my browser:

```
{
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
}
```

What am I missing here? Also ran `setInternet2(TRUE)` first, but got identical results.

Comment: Update for new readers: This bug has been fixed and user_agent() works as of this date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very curious the help page `?user_agent` suggests it should work. You can set a header explicitly and it does work

```
> GET("http://httpbin.org/user-agent", add_headers("user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))
Response [http://httpbin.org/user-agent]
  Status: 200
  Content-type: application/json
{
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
}
```

but the example given in `?user_agent` appears not to.

```
> GET("http://httpbin.org/user-agent", user_agent("Mozilla/5.0") )
Response [http://httpbin.org/user-agent]
  Status: 200
  Content-type: application/json
{
  "user-agent": "curl/7.19.6 Rcurl/1.95.4.1 httr/0.3"
} 
>
```

It is returning

```
> httr:::default_ua()
[1] "curl/7.19.7 Rcurl/1.95.4.1 httr/0.3"
```

My ISP was also doing something funky so you may need:

```
GET("http://httpbin.org/user-agent", add_headers("user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0", "Cache-Control" = "no-cache"))
```

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/97 there was an issue filed on this. It was marked as fixed but I have tried `devtools::install_github("hadley/httr")` and am still having the issues you experienced.

Comment: Thanks for that background check as well ;-)