# Website forbidden when scraping web data in R but works fine in browser

Tags: r, fread, read.csv

I'm trying to import the data here:

https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.series

But when I run

```
fread('https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.series')
```

I get:

```
Error in curl::curl_download(input, tmpFile, mode = "wb", quiet = !showProgress) : 
  HTTP error 403.
```

Update: Still getting error even when using custom user agent in Rstudio Cloud
[image]

Comment: It seems likely the website is monitoring the user-agent and only allow browser-like agent strings. Consider using `httr::GET("...", user_agent("something here"))` where `"something here"` is something like (or exactly) what you find when you go to https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/ in your regular web browser.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4536835/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23545748/3358272

Comment: I think it's still giving me 403. I tried the command: 
httr::GET(url = "https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.series", 
          user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"))

And the output was:
Response [https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.series]
  Date: 2023-05-17 14:51
  Status: 403
  Content-Type: text/html
  Size: 1.32 kB

Comment: Also tried httr::GET(url = "https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.series", 
          add_headers("user-agent" = "Chrome/113.0.0.0")) - same result

Comment: `GET(url="https://...", ...)` works for me, apparently the default `http://` is forbidden.

Comment: I am using "https://" in my code; it's just that when it gets converted to a hyperlink on this website it doesn't show that part of the URL.

Comment: don't know, but when I used the code from your comment and added `"https://"` to the beginning of the URL, I got data, not 403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me at the BLS time series site: preface the url with `"https://"`, and then for the user_agent string, insert your email address instead of the browser string. Ex:

```
GET("https://download.bls.gov/...",user_agent("youremail@domain.name"))
```

Comment: Using an email address is the only solution that worked for me when trying to download data from https://download.bls.gov.

A small correction, however: The python line should be

`requests.get("https://download.bls.gov/...", headers = {"user-agent":"youremail@domain.name"})`

Comment: Followup to my post: The BLS download website has always allowed direct browser access using "Save link as" to save to a file. And, up till early 2023, one could use the Python command requests.get(url) with no additional arguments to download a file from there. I don't know why BLS made the process more difficult; I cannot find anything on their website indicating the above solution. Instead, BLS offers examples of how to download particular timeseries using an API which cannot possibly handle tens of thousands of timeseries.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues addressed here:

1. For the initial failure, we'll use `httr` and its `user_agent` for the query.
2. For the subsequent `GET(..)` failure, we'll prepend `"https://"` to the URL, since it'll otherwise default to `"http://"` (and not all websites automatically redirect port 80 to port 443 with a scheme upgrade).

```r
library(httr)
quux <- GET(url = "download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.series", user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"))
quux
# Response [http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.series]
#   Date: 2023-05-17 17:23
#   Status: 403
#   Content-Type: text/html
#   Size: 1.32 kB
quux <- GET(url = "https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.series", user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"))
quux
# Response [https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.series]
#   Date: 2023-05-17 17:23
#   Status: 200
#   Content-Type: text/plain
#   Size: 1.34 MB
# series_id         area_code   item_code   seasonal    periodicity_code    base_code   base_period series_title    footnote_cod...
# CUSR0000SA0       0000    SA0 S   R   S   1982-84=100 All items in U.S. city average, all urban consumers, seasonally ad...
# CUSR0000SA0E      0000    SA0E    S   R   S   1982-84=100 Energy in U.S. city average, all urban consumers, seasonally adju...
# CUSR0000SA0L1     0000    SA0L1   S   R   S   1982-84=100 All items less food in U.S. city average, all urban consumers, s...
# CUSR0000SA0L12    0000    SA0L12  S   R   S   1982-84=100 All items less food and shelter in U.S. city average, all urban...
# CUSR0000SA0L12E   0000    SA0L12E S   R   S   1982-84=100 All items less food, shelter, and energy in U.S. city average,...
# CUSR0000SA0L12E4  0000    SA0L12E4    S   R   S   1982-84=100 All items less food, shelter, energy, and used cars and truck...
# CUSR0000SA0L1E    0000    SA0L1E  S   R   S   1982-84=100 All items less food and energy in U.S. city average, all urban ...
# CUSR0000SA0L2     0000    SA0L2   S   R   S   1982-84=100 All items less shelter in U.S. city average, all urban consumers...
# CUSR0000SA0L5     0000    SA0L5   S   R   S   1982-84=100 All items  less medical care in U.S. city average, all urban con...
# ...
fread(content(quux))
# No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
#              series_id area_code item_code seasonal periodicity_code base_code       base_period
#                 <char>    <char>    <char>   <char>           <char>    <char>            <char>
#    1:      CUSR0000SA0      0000       SA0        S                R         S       1982-84=100
#    2:     CUSR0000SA0E      0000      SA0E        S                R         S       1982-84=100
#    3:    CUSR0000SA0L1      0000     SA0L1        S                R         S       1982-84=100
#    4:   CUSR0000SA0L12      0000    SA0L12        S                R         S       1982-84=100
#    5:  CUSR0000SA0L12E      0000   SA0L12E        S                R         S       1982-84=100
#    6: CUSR0000SA0L12E4      0000  SA0L12E4        S                R         S       1982-84=100
#    7:   CUSR0000SA0L1E      0000    SA0L1E        S                R         S       1982-84=100
#    8:    CUSR0000SA0L2      0000     SA0L2        S                R         S       1982-84=100
#    9:    CUSR0000SA0L5      0000     SA0L5        S                R         S       1982-84=100
#   10:    CUSR0000SA0LE      0000     SA0LE        S                R         S       1982-84=100
#   ---                                                                                           
# 8090:   CUUSS49GSEHF02      S49G    SEHF02        U                S         S       1982-84=100
# 8091:     CUUSS49GSETA      S49G      SETA        U                S         S DECEMBER 1997=100
# 8092:   CUUSS49GSETA01      S49G    SETA01        U                S         S  JANUARY 1978=100
# 8093:   CUUSS49GSETA02      S49G    SETA02        U                S         S  JANUARY 1978=100
# 8094:     CUUSS49GSETB      S49G      SETB        U                S         S       1982-84=100
# 8095:   CUUSS49GSETB01      S49G    SETB01        U                S         S       1982-84=100
# 8096:     CUUSS49GSETE      S49G      SETE        U                S         S  JANUARY 1978=100
# 8097:  CUUSS49GSS47014      S49G   SS47014        U                S         S       1982-84=100
# 8098:  CUUSS49GSS47015      S49G   SS47015        U                S         S DECEMBER 1993=100
# 8099:  CUUSS49GSS47016      S49G   SS47016        U                S         S       1982-84=100
# 6 variables not shown: [series_title <char>, footnote_codes <lgcl>, begin_year <int>, begin_period <char>, end_year <int>, end_period <char>]
```

Comment: For me it returns 403 regardless of whether I append the https prefix. I thought it was particular to my machine/network, so I tried it on RStudioCloud, and got the same result. Is it possible we are using different versions of httr or one of it's dependencies?

Comment: linux, R-4.2.3, httr-1.4.6, curl-5.0.0